# Problems using a custom history in react-router 2.0.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Specifically I want to use the "basename" option so I can run my application in a sub directory.

I have the following code to set-up the history.

```
var createHistory = require('history').createHistory;
var useRouterHistory = require('react-router').useRouterHistory;
var browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    basename: "/subfolder"
});
```

I then have the following to route config

```
<Router history={browserHistory} className="react-container">
    <Route path="/" component={Template}>
        <IndexRoute component={Diary} />
        <Route path="diary(/:zoom)" component={Diary} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

I can route without any problems in the components themselves using:

```
this.context.router.push('login');
```

But when I try and push a new route to the history in a flux store it doesn't work. It will change the URL in the address bar to the correct value, but the component will not change.
I can refresh the page and it loads as expected.

For example I can use:

```
//require browser history in store
var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory;
....
//after login
browserHistory.push('/');
```

I would expect the "Diary" component to load, but instead it changes the URL to /subfolder and the component stays as the login page.

The routing all works correctly if I just use

```
require('react-router').browserHistory
```

instead of the custom code, but I then can't run the application in a sub directory like I need.

Thanks in advance for any help and tips you can give me.
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Flux store, you need to make sure to use the same history object that you set up for your router.

Comment: Could you add a link to some sort of documentation about this? I have been scouring the react-router documentation and trying many different combos of google searches and unable to find reference to the `<base>` element. I realize that you work on react-router so you know what you're talking about, but all of my searching turns up results that incorporate using the `history` library directly like in the question.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date now. The use of a `<base>` element to set basename is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly the same issue now with react-router@2.8.1

the url in address bar gets updated correct, but nothing happens on UI. If I hit F5, it will work

still investigating on this....